# Weird Behaviour while using HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, treemap

I am trying to fix a code, which I wont be able to post it here, So I have a trimmed down version here.

I am getting a unstable output, while using HashMap.

```
HashMap<Integer, String> test= new HashMap<>(); 
test.put(1, "one");
test.put(2, "one");
test.put(3, "one"); 
test.put(4,"four");
test.put(5, "one");
test.put(6, "one");
test.put(10, "one");
test.put(19, "one");    
test.put(20, "Sixteen");    
System.out.println(test);


HashMap<Integer, String> test3= new HashMap<>(200); 
test3.put(1, "one");
test3.put(2, "one");
test3.put(3, "one");    
test3.put(4,"four");
test3.put(5, "one");
test3.put(6, "one");
test3.put(10, "one");
test3.put(19, "one");   
test3.put(20, "Sixteen");
System.out.println(test3);
```

Outputs

```
test --> {1=one, 19=one, 2=one, 3=one, 4=four, 20=Sixteen, 5=one, 6=one, 10=one}
test3--> {1=one, 2=one, 3=one, 4=four, 5=one, 6=one, 10=one, 19=one, 20=Sixteen}---> My desired output.
```

Why are the results different even though the input values are the same. How is  this sorting differing i.e storing of elements?

I am unable to use the second method as the size is dynamic, it keeps on changing based on the application. Can I use TreeMap for the same and get a consistent  output for all values.

Comment: do you think the size in the 1st method is static?

Comment: HashMap doesn't guarantee the  order - as per the Java API

Comment: You *cannot* use HashMap and expect consistent ordering.  Use LinkedHashMap or TreeMap instead.

Comment: @SpringLearner  No it's not. Right now my concern is. Why the outputs are different when the size differs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Why the outputs are different when the size differs –*

this because while calling the put method of hashmap indexFor(hash,table.length) is called internally. Table.length is different that means default is 16 but for your second way size is 200. so index will be different.

Please read more in this [article](http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2013/08/hashing-how-hash-map-works-in-java-or.html)

*Can I use TreeMap for the same and get a consistent output for all values.*

In Treemap gurantees, keys will be ordered and so you will get `{1=one, 2=one, 3=one, 4=four, 5=one, 6=one, 10=one, 19=one, 20=Sixteen}`

You may use LinkedHashmap if you want to retrieve in the order the way its inserted

Comment: Just one last clarification, So  you mean to say that for HashMap the output result can change over time or when I use it on different Machines. Where in for TreeMap the output will remain constant irrespective of the condition. I cant use LinkedHashMap as the code breaks at many other places when I use it.

Comment: @user2900314 I did not say that the output will change overtime on different machines. I just made the statement why the order is different when you default contructor and argument constructor of hashmap

Answer (score 2):

With HashMaps there is a concept called load factor. The load factor is how full the hashmap can be before it will resize itself. If the load factor is 0.5 (or 50%) then when the hashmap reaches 50% capacity it will resize itself to make room for more elements.

The reason a hashmap generally has a load factor smaller than 100% is because of the way the elements are stored. When you generate a hash you use a hash function. The hash function you are using is the default and is based on the equals() method of the object being stored with some extra twiddling that is not important at the moment. Thing is, two elements can end up with the same hash, it's not guaranteed to be unique. When you try to store two values with the same hash, they end up in the same 'bucket' in the hashmap. This is called a collision. When you have a collision, the hashmap needs a strategy to deal with it.

Sometimes the strategy is 'linear probing'. This means, if an element collides, the hashmap will step through the next few buckets looking for an empty one.

Sometimes the strategy is 'chaining' where, if an element collides, the hashmap will replace the existing element with a linked list and put each of the elements that collide in the list.

All this means is that when elements collide in a hashmap, it becomes slower to insert and slower to retrieve elements. So to reduce the chance of collisions, the hashmap resizes itself according to the load factor.

On top of all this, as others have mentioned, there is no guarantee of ordering in a basic HashMap. You need to use an implemention like LinkedHashMap that does.

Answer (score 1):

That's because

> new HashMap<>() Constructs an empty HashMap with the default initial capacity (16)

So it tends to print values of index 0--->15 and then again from index 16-->31 considered as 0--->15.

Comment: I agree on that, but in the above scenario the size of HashMap does not exceed 16. I was expecting both to give the same result.

Comment: You are putting the values at index 19 and 20. So 19--->3 and 20--->4

Comment: @user2900314 the intital capacity is the number of hash buckets rather than literally the number of objects it can contain.

Comment: @user2900314 If you use new HashMap<>(17); then the indexing will be like 0--->31 & if new HashMap<>(18); then the indexing will be like 0--->63. You know what I mean.

Comment: @Shivam could you please elaborate, Sorry.

Comment: @user2900314 When I use HashMap<>(17) the indexing of the key will be 0--->31 then I am getting the desired output. But if I put test.put(36, "one") then the output is {1=one, 2=one, 3=one, 4=four, 36=one, 5=one, 10=one, 19=one, 20=Sixteen} That means 36--->4
You can also try to understand this.

Answer (score 1):

`HashMap` doesn't give the guarantees as the order. If you want to retrieve the elements in map based on the order you inserted, You can use `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: When i use LinkedHashMap it fails at many other places. So I wont be able to  use it.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on where it fails? .To retrieve in the order the way you insert, You should use `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: In my actual code, the HashMap contains all the values of an xml. and the same code is used by many other applications. When I make the change as  LinkedHashMap, One application gets passed. but it fails at many other place.  Why? I have no idea as I do not have access to those code.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) entry for the `HashMap` class,

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) if you want the keys to be sorted naturally

> The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by
>   a Comparator provided at map creation time, depending on which
>   constructor is used.

```
Map<Integer, String> test= new TreeMap<>(); 
test.put(1, "one");
test.put(2, "one");
test.put(3, "one"); 
test.put(4,"four");
test.put(5, "one");
test.put(6, "one");
test.put(10, "one");
test.put(19, "one");    
test.put(20, "Sixteen");    
System.out.println(test); // Output : {1=one, 2=one, 3=one, 4=four, 5=one, 6=one, 10=one, 19=one, 20=Sixteen}
```

Answer (score 0):

HashMap with the default initial capacity (16)

{1=one, 2=one, 3=one, 4=four, 5=one, 6=one, 10=one}

{1=one, 2=one, 3=one, 4=four, 5=one, 6=one, 10=one}